# Best way to preforms queries on large array in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, database, performance

I currently have a table in my Postgres database with about 115k rows that I feel is too slow for my serverless functions. The only thing I need that table for is to lookup values using functions like ILIKE and the network barrier is slowing things down a lot I believe.

My thought was to take the table and make it into a javascript array of objects as it doesn't change often if ever. Now that I have it in a file such as array.ts and inside is:

```
export default [
{}, {}, {},...
]
```

What is the best way to query this huge array? Is it best to just use the .filter function? I currently am trying to import the array and filter it but it seems to just hang and never actually complete. MUCH slower the the current DB approach so I am unsure if this is the right approach.

Comment: 115K length array of object is not a good idea at all. Managing it would be a bigger problem even worse than now. If network is your bottleneck, why don't you upgrade network?

Comment: If you not sure about the bottleneck is network, explain the query through db tool by doing so you can tell whether query itself is slow.

Comment: @hellikiam If I run the query locally it takes about 50-100ms which is fine for my use case. The problem is on the cloud functions it takes about 300ms - 500ms which is slower than I would like. The database is stored on a google compute engine and the access is done through google cloud functions so I can't really upgrade the network I think.

Comment: 1. Is that the network response time or database query type? 2.Upgrading your cloud computing resource is also impossible?

Comment: I think what you're planning to do is too dangerous brother. Plz, don't do this in code level, but other level

Comment: Have you measured how long it takes to establish the database connection? It may be that the time taken to create the connection is the issue, rather than the actual query time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Make the database faster

As people have commented, it's likely that the database will actually perform better than anything else given that databases are good at indexing large data sets. It may just be a case of adding the right index, or changing the way your serverless functions handle the connection pool.

### Make local files faster

If you want to do it without the database, there are a couple of things that will make a big difference:

1. Read the file and then use `JSON.parse`, do not use `require(...)`

JavaScript is much slower to parse than JSON. You can therefore make things load much faster by parsing it as JavaScript.

2. Find a way to split up the data

Especially in a serverless environment, you're unlikely to need all the data for every request, and the serverless function will probably only serve a few requests before it is shutdown and a new one is started.

If you could split your files up such that you typically only need to load an array of 1,000 or so items, things will run much faster.

Depending on the size of the objects, you might consider having a file that contains only the id of the objects & the fields needed to filter them, then having a separate file for each object so you can load the full object after you have filtered.

### Use a local database

If the issue is genuinely the network latency, and you can't find a good way to split up the files, you could try using a local database engine.

[@databases/sqlite](https://www.atdatabases.org/docs/sqlite) can be used to query an SQLite database file that you could pre-populate with your array of values and index appropriately.

```
const openDatabase = require('@databases/sqlite');
const {sql} = require('@databases/sqlite');

const db = openDatabase('mydata.db');

async function query(pattern) {
  await db.query(sql`SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_name LIKE ${pattern}`);
}

query('%foo%').then(results => console.log(results));
```